# How to remove the category from the url only for a specific category of articles on wordpress

Tags: categories, permalinks

I'm using a permalink structure like this on a wordpress : **/%category%/%postname%**

But i'd like a category of articles to appear without the prefix **/%category%/**

ex : right now it's appearing like that : **example.com/catname1/post**

but i'd like it to be **example.com/post**

This only for the post in catname1 and keep the structure **example.com/catname2/post** for the other categories.

I found a few plugins that may have this option but none for free and I'd like to know if it's doable in php as it's only one category and I don't want to bloat the website with another plugin if possible.

I tried a few solution that were posted on stack overflow but none of them worked or suited for what I'm looking for.

I tried this code which change the url displayed but I get a 404 error when following it:

```
function my_pre_post_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
    if( $post->post_type != 'post' ) return $permalink;
    $cats = get_the_category($post->ID);
    if( ! count($cats) ) return $permalink;
  
    usort($cats, '_usort_terms_by_ID');
    $category_object = apply_filters( 'post_link_category', $cats[0], $cats, $post );
  
    $category_object = get_term( $category_object, 'category' );
  
    return _clear_uncategorized($category_object, $permalink);
  }
  
  function _clear_uncategorized($cat, $permalink) {
    if( $cat->slug == 'catname' ) {
      return str_replace('%category%/', '', $permalink);
    }
    $parent = $cat->parent;
    if ( !$parent )
      return $permalink;
    return _clear_uncategorized($parent, $permalink);
  }
  
  add_filter( 'pre_post_link', 'my_pre_post_link', 9, 3 );
```

Comment: Did you flush the permalinks after you implemented your code? If not—or if you're not sure—go to your site's admin pages and select **Settings** → **Permalinks**, then click **Save Changes** (you don't need to change anything on the settings page).

Comment: YesI did flush it